# My IDL loop only saves the last iteration - how can I fix it?

Tags: idl-programming-language

I am trying to write a loop to process daily data for a whole month. My code works when manually doing 1 day at a time, but something about my loop is failing when i try to loop through every day of the month.

Basically I'm looping through n = 1,30 days to read in files, clip data to my study area, and add data from each additional day to my array of data. I want one array containing data for the whole month.

These are functions in my loop:

`@mls_choosefile_co.pro` --> this just gives me the 'ToOpen' file path+name

`@mls_readin_co.pro` --> this uses the file_id to read in the CO data and clip it to my study area. Output is 'co_sa_100', for CO in study area at 100 hpa, a 1x700 array (length varies by day, may be 706, 720, 680...)

^^ Both of these work fine on their own.

```
; make array of data for the whole month - CO at 100hpa
; to append each additional day to this on each loop iteration
    co_100_all = [ ] 
; make array to save how many data points per day. use -9 as a fill value to tell me when the loop has not gone over that day. 
    len = MAKE_ARRAY(1,ndays, VALUE = -9)

; the loop in question: 
    FOR n = 0,ndays DO BEGIN &$
        @mls_choosefile_co.pro &$
        file_id = H5F_OPEN(ToOpen) &$
        @mls_readin_co.pro &$
        len[n-1] = N_ELEMENTS(co_sa_100) &$
        co_100_all = [[co_100_all], [co_sa_100]] &$
    END
```

I set up the 'len' variable as a test. This will tell me how many data points have been read in per day, with a value per day (usually around 700). I've set -9 as a fill value for where the loop is not operating. It should read something like:
len = [702, 716, 706]. 
but it only ever saves the last index in the loop and I get: 
len = [-9, -9, 706].

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Update: its been fixed!

My problem was with calling the functions using `@program.pro` rather than in `program, input, output` format.

Loops through `n` number of days, pulls out data for the chemical named `'tracer'`, and saves the `output` for each day to the `saveoutputs` array.

Here's the edited code, in case it helps anyone:

```
FOR n = 0, ndays-1 DO BEGIN
    mls_choosefile, n, tracer, file_id
    mls_readin, file_id, tracer, output
    mls_len[n-1] = N_ELEMENTS(output)
    saveoutputs[n,*] = output
END
```

Where `mls_choosefile` and `mls_readin` are set up as IDL procedures.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with my IDL code too. My variable 'm' has ~17700 data points in the array and when I >print,m or >plot m,a ...only the last point was being printed or plotted.

So the alternative I tried is to save the data points on a .dat file using 'append' and then plot it.

openu,1,'m.dat',/append
printf,1,m
free_lun,1

plot,m,a,yrange=1,6.2],xstyle=1,ystyle=1,xtitle='Magnetic Local Time',ytitle='Voltage [volts]',position=[0.06, 0.10, 0.97, 0.95]

This worked for me. The key point is using the 'append' function.